# Find Integer Partition using only integers belonging to S = { 1, 2, 3 }

Tags: integer-partitions, set-partition

I spent all afternoon looking for this but I wasn't able to find anything, so...
Is there a formula to know the NUMBER of partitions with a constraint on the integer domain ?

E.g.: Find the number of partitions of 5 only using integers belonging to S = {1,2,3}

**p(5) -> 13**

Since p(5):

1. [1,1,1,1,1]
2. [1,1,1,2]
3. [1,1,2,1]
4. [1,2,1,1]
5. [2,1,1,1]
6. [2,2,1]
7. [2,1,2]
8. [1,2,2]
9. [1,1,3]
10. [1,3,1]
11. [3,1,1]
12. [3,2]
13. [2,3]

Comment: Usually in giving a partition of an integer, order is not important.  So one would not generally distinguish between 1, 2, 3 and 3, 1, 2 as partitions of $6$.  Is your intent to consider 'ordered' partitions as you did in your example?

Comment: What kind of constrain? Are you interested in the order of numbers to be summed?

Comment: @paw88789 Yes, in my case order is important, so 1 2 3 and 3 1 2 are different partitions of 6.

Comment: Suggestion: Try writing a recurrence equation for this problem.

Comment: @paw88789 Mmm thanks, I think I found the right solution. It seems a generalization of the FIbonacci sequence.


$$
P(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} P(n-i)
$$

where $P(1) = 1$ , $P(2) = 2$ and $P(3) = 4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem can be solved using a recurrence equation.

If we suppose  $ n > m $ the number of ordered partitions of *$n$* will be:
$$
P_{k}(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} P_{k}(n-i)
$$

Where $P_{3}(1) = 1$ , $P_{3}(2) = 2$ and $P_{3}(3) = 4$.

If we think about it the first number in our partition can be any number up to $m$.

So e.g. $n = 5$ and $m = 3$

- **Start = 3**

  $[3, 1, 1]$ , $[3, 2]$

  $->$ **2** partitions {$P_{3}(5-3) = P_{3}(2)$}
- **Start = 2**

  $[2, 1, 1, 1]$ , $[2, 2, 1]$ , $[2, 1, 2]$ , $[2, 3]$

  $->$ **4** partitions {$P_{3}(5-2) = P_{3}(3)$}
- **Start = 1**

  $[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$ , $[1, 1, 1, 2]$ , $[1, 1, 2, 1]$ , $[1, 2, 1, 1]$ , $[1, 1, 3]$ , 
  $[1, 3, 1]$ , $[1, 2, 2]$

  $->$ **7** partitions {$P_{3}(5-1) = P_{3}(4)$}

**Finally:**

$P_{3}(5) = P_{3}(4) + P_{3}(3) + P_{3}(2) = 7 + 4 + 2 = 13$

Comment: It's arguably slightly easier to use base case $P_3(0) = 1$ instead of $P_3(4) = 4$.

Comment: How to explain such a recursion relation?Thank you.